Narrowing multiple variables based on a module-level constant narrowed in branches
I'm trying to narrow down the types of multiple elements based on a module-level constant that is narrowed inside certain branches. However, it seems that TypeScript is only able to narrow down the types if I use a predicate function for each element individually or if I type them as conditional types inside the specific branch.
I tried with branded types, conditional types and seems like you have to narrow one by one. But for my use case this is not ergonomic. Is there any way to hint TS to exploit those correlations between types?
Using branded types and type predicates (playground) :
const condition = Math.random() > 0.5;

type onlyTrue<T> = T & { brand: "true" };
type onlyFalse<T> = T & { brand: "false" };

const a: onlyTrue<number> = 123 as any;
const b: onlyFalse<string> = "abc" as any;
const u = condition ? a : b;
const u2 = condition ? a : b;

type NarrowTrue<T> = Extract<T, onlyTrue<any>>;

function trueBranch(x: any): x is NarrowTrue<typeof a> {
  return condition;
}

if (trueBranch(u)) {
  u;
  u2; // not narrowed down
}

if (condition) {
  u; // not narrowed down.
  u2; // not narrowed down.
}

Using conditional types (playground):
const condition = Math.random() > 0.5;

type ConditionalType<X> = X extends true ? number : string;

function conditional<X>(value: any) {
  return value as X extends true ? number:string
}

const u = conditional<typeof condition>(condition? 1 : "a")
const t = (condition ? 1 : "a") as ConditionalType<typeof condition>;

if (condition) {
  t; u; // not narrowed down.
  const t2 = condition ? 1 : "a"; // not narrowed down

  // If we defer the conditional into the if branch then TS correctly narrows them down
  const u3 = conditional<typeof condition>(condition? 1 : "a")
  const t3 = (condition ? 1 : "a") as ConditionalType<typeof condition>;
}

I am looking for a faster way to narrow many types down that depends on one shared constant. Is there any approach I am not seeing?
Thanks

IIRC you need to do something like const {u, u2} = condition ? {u: a, u2: a} : {u: b, u2: b}; to make TypeScript realise that they are dependent on each other. I might misremember though and this only works for discriminated unions.

Yeah there's no way to do anything like this without building a big discriminated union, packaging all the values together into one object, either before or after you try to narrow. Like, maybe this version? But it's not really what you want. You're looking for the feature requested at ms/TS#43786 but it's not part of the language and has very little community engagement so I doubt it ever will be. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz  Yeah, this answers the question. It seems like discriminated unions are the best approach for this. I will add my use case to the feature request. I guess this cannot be done with a TypeScript plugin. Although it is not clear based on what the plugin capabilities are.

Currently the only way for a check on one variable to narrow other variables is if those variables are destructured from a discriminated union and if the variable you check is the discriminant of that union.  So one could write
const [c, u, u2] = condition ?
  [condition, a, a] :
  [condition, b, b]

and then use c to narrow u and u2:
if (c) {
  u.toFixed()
  u2.toExponential()
} else {
  u.toUpperCase()
  u2.toLowerCase()
}

But it's not really what you're looking for, since it requires that you package all of the variables you care about into a single object. You might as well just use a plain discriminated union for all the good that does:
const obj = condition ?
  { condition, u: a, u2: a } : 
  { condition, u: b, u2: b }
if (obj.condition) {
  obj.u.toFixed()
  obj.u2.toExponential()
} else {
  obj.u.toUpperCase()
  obj.u2.toLowerCase()
}

And you can't use a custom type guard function to get around this, because type predicates like arg is Type can only refer to function parmeters (or this), not variables from an outer scope.  So unless you actually pass u and u2 into your type guard function, it can't narrow them.  And you can't narrow multiple parameters with a type guard function, so you'd have to package them all in a single object again, which is really no better than a discriminated union object.  There are various feature requests like microsoft/TypeScript#26916 to allow for narrowing multiple parameters in a type guard function, and microsoft/TypeScript#41173 to allow for narrowing destructured single parameters in a type guard function, and microsoft/TypeScript#43786 to allow for narrowing values not passed into a type guard function. But none of those are part of the language currently, so I don't see any way to use type guard functions to significantly help.  At best you can avoid putting the condition into the union object:
const obj2 = condition ? 
  { u: a, u2: a } : 
  { u: b, u2: b }

function trueBranch<T extends object>(x: T):
  x is { [K in keyof T]: Extract<T[K], { brand: "true" }> } {
  return condition;
}

if (trueBranch(obj2)) {
  obj2.u.toFixed();
  obj2.u2.toExponential()
} else {
  obj2.u.toUpperCase();
  obj2.u2.toLowerCase();
}

But that doesn't seem like much of a win.
Playground link to code
